# Clicking AJAX buttons on Facebook w/ mechanize and Python

Tags: python, mechanize, spidermonkey

So I've been trying to create a script that clears all my activity on Facebook by going to the  activity log and clicking all the buttons to either delete, or if it can't hide, all posts. Mechanize allows me to log into my account, and navigate to the page. Once there though, clicking the buttons is difficult, since they use javascript. I've heard spidermonkey works well for evaluating javascript, but I was wondering how you could patch it onto mechanize so that it will work with the AJAX Facebook uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to instrument a normal browser and do what you want.

It's probably possible to use spidermonkey to evaluate javascript, or do something with [node.js](http://nodejs.org), but my guess is it would be more complicated and more brittle.

Comment: Alright... The selenium docs look fairly dense, but I did do an easy_install and now have selenium running. Know of a good place to start from?

Comment: You could play around with Selenium IDE to record some sessions or something. But since you're already using python, you'd probably just want to fire up the Selenium server and pull up a python prompt, import it, and start experimenting with it.